# Store a Dynamic HTML class as a JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dynamic, google-tag-manager

I am trying to tag a multi-step quiz with Google Tag Manager, and the only way to do this for what we need is to create a variable to track which page the user is on. This entire quiz is stored inside of an iframe.

Below is an example for better understanding:

```
<div class="quiz-page-1">Quiz Page</div>
<div class="quiz-page-2">Quiz Page</div>
<div class="quiz-page-3">Quiz Page</div>
<div class="quiz-page-4">Quiz Page</div>
```

I am looking for some way to store this changing class in one single variable.

---

Sorry if this has been posted before. I couldnt find anything when searching.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be fully understanding the questions here, but it sounds like you just need a global variable:

to 'store' the element:

```
var GLOBAL_CLASS = document.querySelector('.quiz-page-1');
```

to 'store' the class:

```
var GLOBAL_CLASS = 'quiz-page-1';
```

to 'store' the DOMTokenList of classes for that element:

```
var GLOBAL_CLASS = document.querySelector('.quiz-page-1').classList;
```

Comment: This would normally work, but Im restricted within Google Tag Manager which is why I am looking for a workaround.

I appreciate the post though!